# Specilization of a member function of a templated class is not working

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I'm trying to define a specialization for a member operator of a templated `struct` like this:

```
template<typename T = double>
struct vec2 {
    T x, y;

    vec2(const T x,
         const T y)
    : x{x}, y{y} {}

    vec2(const T w)
    : vec2(w, w) {}

    vec2()
    : vec2(static_cast<T>(0)) {}

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const vec2& v) {
        os << "vec2<" << v.x << ", " << v.y << ">";
        return os;
    }

    vec2<T> operator%(const T f) const;
};

template<> template<>
vec2<int> vec2<int>::operator%(const int f) const {
    return vec2(x % f, y % f);
}

template<> template<>
vec2<double> vec2<double>::operator%(const double f) const{
    return vec2(std::fmod(x, f), std::fmod(y, f));
}

int main() {
    vec2 v1(5.0, 12.0);
    vec2<int> v2(5, 12);
    cout << v1 % 1.5 << v2 % 2 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm facing 2 problems:

- compiler can't find any matching declaration for both of the specialized `%` operator

  `error: template-id ‘operator%<>’ for ‘vec2<int> vec2<int>::operator%(int) const’ does not match any template declaration`
- compiler can't use the default template parameter for declaration of `vec2 v1` and expects template arguments for it

  `error: missing template arguments before ‘v1’`

Now aren't these full specialization of `struct vec2`? So I should be able to specialize the member function as well?

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`template<> template<>` is an attempt to specialize a member inside another specialization. Since `operator%` is not a function template, you need only one `template<>` to indicate a full specialization of `vec2`, e.g.:

```
template <>
vec2<int> vec2<int>::operator%(const int f) const
{
    return vec2(x % f, y % f);
}
```

`vec2` is a class template, not a type. In order to create a type from a class template that defaults its template parameters, you need an empty pair of brackets:

```
vec2<> v1(5.0, 12.0);
// ~^^~
```

or create a typedef for it:

```
typedef vec2<> vec2d;
vec2d v1(5.0, 12.0);
```

Comment: Just curious, shouldn't the constructor arguments help the compiler to deduce the template argument type as well, `double` in this case?

Comment: @Samik class template arguments are never deduced from constructor argument expressions, and it's also not related to your case. as I said `vec2`, is a name that refers to a class template, not a type